# How to change rotation center of an orbit animation in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, realitykit

Apple's *RealityKit* provides `OrbitAnimation` to let an entity orbit around the point (0,0,0).

Is there any way to change the center of rotation to (x,y,z) instead of the origin?

I have checked [RealityKit documentation for struct OrbitAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/orbitanimation) but haven't found any property or method to change the center of rotation. But maybe the animation could be assigned to another point, entity's position or coordinate system so that the origin translates accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reality Composer Pro, you can open the scene and adjust the model's position.

[image: screenshot of reality composer pro]

`OrbitAnimation` now orbits around that position.